# Print column next to the column matching a pattern

Tags: awk, sed

I have this tab separated file:

```
gene        1  A  6  gene_name  TP53       B
exon        6  B  2  2          A          gene_name  MYC2  10.0  B
transcript  3  B  B  4          gene_name  ORF1
```

How can I print the first column plus the next column after `gene_name` column? As you can see, `gene_name` do not exist always in the same column.

I am not sure about how to get the last part of this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {print $1, ??}' myFile.tsv
```

So, my expected output is:

```
gene TP53
exon MYC2
transcript ORF1
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can even use `sed` for this, `sed -nE 's/^(\S+).*\sgene_name(\s+\S+).*/\1\2/p' file` (GNU) ([demo](https://ideone.com/Sd6zW6)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following.

***1st solution:*** In case you have multiple `gene_name` values in single line then following may help.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="gene_name"){print $1,$(i+1);i++}}}' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** In case you have only 1 `gene_name` then use following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="gene_name"){print $1,$(i+1);next}}}' Input_file
```

***3rd solution:*** With your very specific case where `gene_name` always coming on 3rd field we could try this one, for Generic ones try 1st or 2nd solutions.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} $3=="gene_name"{print $1,$4}' Input_file
```

OR if you want to check 2nd last field and print last field value then use:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} $(NF-1)=="gene_name"{print $(NF-1),$NF}' Input_file
```

***4th solution:*** With `sed` please try following.

```
sed -E 's/(\S+).*gene_name\s+(\S+).*/\1\t\2/' Input_file
```

Comment: For the sed solution perhaps `sed -nE 's/\s.*gene_name(\s\S+).*/\1/p' file` N.B. There is only a single `\s` following `gene_name` otherwise an empty field or series of empty fields may be mistook for the desired one.

Answer (score 4):

You may use this `gnu awk` solution:

```sh
awk '{print gensub(/^(\S+).*\tgene_name\t(\S+).*/, "\\1\t\\2", "1")}' file
gene    TP53
exon    MYC2
transcript  ORF1
```

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU grep:

```sh
grep -oP '(^\S+)|(\bgene_name\s+\K\S+)' myFile.tsv | paste - -
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{v=$1; sub(/.* gene_name /,""); print v, $1}' file
gene    TP53
exon    MYC2
transcript      ORF1
```

Answer (score 1):

And also with `awk`:

```
awk -v FS=' .*gene_name | ' '{print $1,$2}' file
gene TP53
exon MYC2
transcript ORF1
```